# Want to know about WESAD Dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, data-analysis, wearables

I'm now working on a project "Stress classification using wearables" for which I'm using the most used dataset for this probem - "WESAD Dataset". I converted one subject's (s2) pkl file into csv by downsampling the values to 4 Hz because the wrist parameters were all sampled different unline the chest paramters which is sampled to 700 Hz. I wanted to know what's in the zip file of each subject that contains different CSV files for each wrist parameter, It doesn't sync up with the number of values in the pickle file of each subject.

I tried checking the values in the separate csv files of wrist sensors and looked up with the values for the parameters in the pickle file, it doesn't sync up well and also the number of values doesn't match.

[Link to download dataset](https://uni-siegen.sciebo.de/s/HGdUkoNlW1Ub0Gx)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.